# PHP: Mix part of an array with another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array of variable size wich is going to contain items

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 126264027457298
        [qty] => 6
        [price] => 55.85
        [shipping] => 6.00
        [fbids] =>  12
        [imgids] => 126264027457298
        [albids] => 126263974123970
        [thumbs] => https://268088_126264027457298_100002211034371_220013_7172874_n.jpg
        [infos] => This is the product name of Item 1
        [subtotal] => 371.1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 126265084123859
        [qty] => 6
        [price] => 25.85
        [shipping] => 6.00
        [fbids] =>  11
        [imgids] => 126265084123859
        [albids] => 126263974123970
        [thumbs] => https://261288_126265084123859_100002211034371_220039_5639038_n.jpg
        [infos] => This is the product name of Item 2
        [subtotal] => 191.1
    )
)
```

And I would like to take part of this array ([qty],[price],[infos]) for each items (no matter of few or many there are) and add it to another array which is formed as follow:

```
Array
(
    [cmd] => _cart
    [upload] => 1
    [business] => xxxxx@xxxxx.com
    [return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/return.php
    [cancel_return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/cancel.php
    [currency_code] => EUR
    [lc] => FR
)
```

The result should look like shown below, so for each item that is going to be added to the array, [item_name_X], [quantity_X] and [amount_X] should increase.

```
Array
(
    [cmd] => _cart
    [upload] => 1
    [business] => xxxxx@xxxxx.com
    [return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/return.php
    [cancel_return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/cancel.php
    [currency_code] => EUR
    [lc] => FR
    [item_name_1] => This is the product name of Item 1
    [quantity_1] => 6
    [amount_1] => 55.85
    [item_name_2] => This is the product name of Item 2
    [quantity_2] => 6
    [amount_2] => 25.85
 )
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) What you propose to do sounds like a bad idea. Tomorrow you may be be asking how  to parse the `quantity_X` items back into an array.

Comment: Hi Jon and thanks for the help! I'm a graphic artist and I'm just starting programming. This is why I'm asking if this is doable and should be done. So far, from reading the PHP manual, I made a copy of my array and removed the data I didn't need and tried to merge it with the other array using array_merge. What I'm trying to do is creating a form to submit to paypal checkout with the data above. Instead of trying to merge the array, should I rather create a function that take the as arguments the data from array 2 and pass array 1 as argument of the function and build the form from there?

Comment: If you are just going to feed the data to paypal then it's fine (I gave a general warning since I didn't know the context). Try out some of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($firstArray as $number => $sub) {

     $secondArray["item_name_" . ($number + 1)] = $sub["infos"];
     $secondArray["qty_" . ($number + 1)] = $sub["qty"];

       etc


 }
```

Comment: Hi stereofrog and thanks for posting. This sounds like a great solution. I'll go and try this.

Comment: I just tried it... and it's working nicely. I cannot beleive it was that easy! I'm glad I finally asked about this. Thanks a lot stereofrog!

Answer (score 0):

If i were you, i would actually do it like this:

```
    Array
(
    [cmd] => _cart
    [upload] => 1
    [business] => xxxxx@xxxxx.com
    [return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/return.php
    [cancel_return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/cancel.php
    [currency_code] => EUR
    [lc] => FR
    [products] => array(
       "ItemName1" => array( 
           "Qty" => 6
           "Total" => xxx
       ),
       ...
    )

)
```

Comment: Hi NineAllexis. I guess this would make sense. But I'm trying to have a simple array as key=> value so I could build a form to post to paypal checkout. I won't need to access the data from that array after this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looping through the items adding the fields of intrest to a sub array:

```
foreach ($itemsArray as $item) {

    $wantedFields = array('qty','price','infos');
    $tempArray = array();

    foreach ($wantedFields as $field) {
        $tempArray[$field] = $item[$field];
    }

    $cartArray['products'][] = $tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! I've used stereofrog code posted above... because it's short, I understand what it does and he got here first. :o) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you append the entire first array to the second one like this :

```
Array
(
    [cmd] => _cart
    [upload] => 1
    [business] => xxxxx@xxxxx.com
    [return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/return.php
    [cancel_return] => http://www.mysite.com/paypal/cancel.php
    [currency_code] => EUR
    [lc] => FR
    [products] = Array
                (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 126264027457298
                        [qty] => 6
                        [price] => 55.85
                        [shipping] => 6.00
                        [fbids] =>  12
                        [imgids] => 126264027457298
                        [albids] => 126263974123970
                        [thumbs] => https://268088_126264027457298_100002211034371_220013_7172874_n.jpg
                        [infos] => This is the product name of Item 1
                        [subtotal] => 371.1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 126265084123859
                        [qty] => 6
                        [price] => 25.85
                        [shipping] => 6.00
                        [fbids] =>  11
                        [imgids] => 126265084123859
                        [albids] => 126263974123970
                        [thumbs] => https://261288_126265084123859_100002211034371_220039_5639038_n.jpg
                        [infos] => This is the product name of Item 2
                        [subtotal] => 191.1
                    )
                )
)
```

You are going to be able to access any product like this :

```
$array2['products'][0]['id'], $array2['products'][1]['id']
```

Hence no restriction of number of items, and no restriction on the data you need to access.

Plus, no parsing is needed.

So in the end :

```
$array2['products'] = $array1;
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thomas! I'm simply creating the array to SSL encode the data and pass it to paypal checkout so a simple array is easier in my case. I should have been mentioning this earlier. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

By principle, this is how [user187291 answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441459/php-mix-part-of-an-array-with-another-array/7441536#7441536) while some little differences: First creating an array which solely contains the elements you would like to merge into the cart array and then merging it.

Additionally it contains a map so that you can specify which elements from the first array should be taken over by with which name:

```
# create an array with the items to add

$addItems = array();
$map = array('infos' => 'item_name', 'qty' => 'quantity', 'price' => 'amount');
$count = 0;
foreach($firstArray as $product)
{
    $count++;
    foreach($map as $from => $to)
    {
        $addItems["$to_$count"] = $product[$from]
    }
}

# merge

$cart += $addItems;
```

Just reading your comment, you can wrap it into a function, which I think is a good idea:

```
$cart = add_items_to_cart($items, $cart);

/**
 * add items to cart
 *
 * @param array $items items to add to cart
 * @param array $cart cart without items
 * @return array cart with items
 */
function add_items_to_cart(array $items, array $cart)
{
    # map
    $addItems = array();
    $map = array('infos' => 'item_name', 'qty' => 'quantity', 'price' => 'amount');
    $count = 0;
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
        $count++;
        foreach($map as $from => $to)
        {
            $addItems["$to_$count"] = $item[$from]
        }
    }

    # merge    
    $cart += $addItems;

    return $cart;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot hakre. Amazing to see so many ways there are to solve a problem.

Comment: There is always more than one way :)